# react gatsby: adding css class dynamically not working in prod build

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby

I need to add a css class dynamically on a div. For this I've set the css class like this:-

```
const Container = ({ divClass }) => {
  const [cssClass, setcssClass] = useState(divClass)
  return (
    <div id="containerDiv" className={cssClass} ></div>
    {/* <div id="containerDiv" className={divClass} ></div>   even this doesn't work*/}
  )
}
```

This works as expected in development build, but doesn't work in prod build. Even without using state if I set class to `divClass` it's not working in prod build.

It only works after I set state using `setcssClass`, like this-

```
const Container = ({ divClass }) => {
  const [cssClass, setcssClass] = useState(divClass)
  return (
    <div id="containerDiv" className={cssClass} onClick={() => setcssClass('testtt')}></div>
  )
}
```

Can anypone please explain this discrepancy in development and production build?

Comment: What is the initial value of `divClass`?

Comment: initial value of `divClass`  is set properly, but it's value on subsequent render is not set as class

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not working on your first try because at the moment you are defining `const [cssClass, setcssClass] = useState(divClass)`, your `<div>` and it's class (`divClass` or `cssClass`) is not defined yet.

The solution is to use a `useEffect` hook with empty deps (`[]`) since it's a function that is triggered once the DOM tree is loaded (and your `<div>` in it).

I wouldn't recommend the approach of the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63794578/5585371) (besides being effective) because it impacts directly the DOM and that's the reason why you are using React and not jQuery (you creating a virtual DOM to manipulate). You can achieve the same result by using a React-based approach with [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) hook.

```
const Container = ({ divClass }) => {
  const containerDivRef = useRef(null);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    containerDivRef.current.classList.add(divClass)
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={containerDivRef}></div>
  )
}
```

Your `<div>` information is stored inside the `containerDivRef.current` exactly in the same way that using `document.querySelector` but without affecting the DOM.

The discrepancy that you mention between `develop` and `build` is caused by the webpack's assets treatment and Gatsby's configuration. Since with a `gatsby develop` (runtime) allows you to use browser's APIs (such as `window`, `document`, other global or DOM objects) in the `gatsby build` (buildtime) the code is processed in the server-side, where those variables are not allowed (even created), that's why you usually should wait for them. You can check for further details in the [Overview of the Gatsby Build Process documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/).

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer Ferran. But one thing that I don't get is how come this works on develop build ? Develop and production build shouldn't work differently.

Comment: I was updating my answer by adding this feedback. Hope it helps!

Comment: And shouldn't it be `ref={containerDivRef}`

Comment: I was also fixing this. `develop` and `build` usually work in the exactly same way. They may differ if you use a global object (such a `window` or `document`, etc). You should double-check your project when using that kind of objects or any third-party library that uses a `window` to make some calculations to ensure that works fine in `build` mode too.

Comment: As you might have noticed that current code is not dependent on `window` or `document`, still i'm facing this.

Comment: let me dig the docs to better understand the difference.

Comment: It's dependant on the DOM, which is not defined at the moment you are requesting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Container = ({ divClass }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const containerDiv = document.querySelector("#containerDiv");

    containerDiv.classList.add(divClass);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="containerDiv"></div>
  )
}
```

Have you tried manipulating the dom manually inside `useEffect`?

I know this might not be the most ideal solution but maybe it solves the problem. lol

Comment: Hi Joimee, thanks for your answer, yes it solves the problem, but I wanted to know why code is functioning differently in prod and dev build